# Filtering user access based on tabled responses

Tags: oop, database-design, language-agnostic, filtering

I am building a "Survey" type application.  The user answers a set of questions with pre-vetted answers.

```
Question: Where do you live?
Answers: England, Finland, Spain, France, Monrovia
```

The answers in this case would be in a DropDownList.

Once the user has completed the basic responses (location, age, sex etc) I would like to be able to prevent them accessing the rest of the survey based on their answers.

So for example, if they live anywhere but England I want to direct them to a page which says "Thanks, but Monrovian's can't complete this survey".  I need my filtering to be user configurable (Table based) and I need to be able to have ANDs and ORs.
So one filter being the user MUST earn 100k+ a year.
Another being they must either live in Spain, or be female AND like model trains - "100k+ && (Spain || (Female && Trains))"

I would usually use Enums and bitmasking for this, but as my country list is 200+ items long, I can't think of a sensible way to store the filtering.

Hopefully I have made some sense and someone has a decent solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I can answer your question completely, but I'll try...

So, we have a bunch of Views that are only visible to the user if she previously chose some answers, like, she will see view#3 if she is older that 30, and view#4 if she is younger than 30 AND from China, and view#5 if she is older than 40 AND from Spain OR Italy, and so on...I want also to introduce the notion of **step**, and for each step we could have 1, 2, or more corresponding views. Each view should have a set of rules (like the ones above) that define if it is displayed or not.

How to create these rules? These rules could be simple instances of a Filter class/interface that, when asked, should return true/false. Like this:

```
interface Filter {
     boolean apply();
}
```

Then you can create Filters like 'older than 30', 'from Spain', whatever. Remember that each view is configured with a set of rules (Filters) so it can answer yes/no if asked if it can display itself.

Next, how to apply these filters?
We could have a controller object that only knows about **steps** (each step can have one or more corresponding views, as I said), and, after the user pressed **next** at the current step, it should collect the answers and apply them against the rules attached to each view. Like, take the answers from step one, and apply them to all views from step two, and see which one matches (returns true). For example, at step two, you can have two separate views, one for young people, other for old people, and you apply the rules from each view to decide if you show the old or young view. 
I could give you one code example, and you could also do research on your own, since I know nothing about your technical environment. I have used Google Guava's predicates on a similar problem and here it is: suppose we are dealing with Witch objects, and each of them has name(string), age(int) and spells(collection) attributes. If I have a list of witches and I need to sort them based on specific criteria, I can do:

```
// first I want to sort witches by age(natural ordering) then by spells, 
// and then by name lexicographically
Ordering.natural()
    .compound(new BySpellsWitchOrdering())
    .compound(new ByNameWitchOrdering())
    .sortedCopy(witchList);
```

The above line of code is going to take the witch list and return a list of sorted witches according to the criteria. Your situation is pretty similar.

Next, how to create the answers? For each view(page), you have possible answers, like, for view#1, you can have : age, sex, race, country. You can construct some answers, in the form of strings, ints, enums, and pass them to the controller, which in turn is going to apply them to each view corresponding to the next step.

As for how to store the rules in the database, as an example, you could have a column defining rule name (like, OLDER THAN) and one column for value, say, 30. Again, I do not know that much about your environment, and it is a really general issue, so I will stop here...

Comment: SQL Server 2012 - I don't want hundreds of columns/rows for each possible filter combination, and I can't use masking (more than 64 items).  I guess I could store a gigantic xml field, but it all seems messy.  Thanks for your answer, although not too helpful in pointing me to a solution, it was interesting, and I'm sure it will be useful in the future :-)

Comment: Also, I'm not concerned with the frontend implementation.  I'm only concerned with how you would store sets of rules in the DB which would allow for dynamic extensions and not look like "smelly"... :-)